# Differential Equations for a Teardrop Shape

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

My research has led me to a nonlinear system of differential equations which should yield a teardrop shape in the $x-y$ plane. The equations, parameterized by $t$ are

$$\frac{x'''}{x'}=\frac{y'''}{y'}$$
$$x'^2+y'^2=1$$

Some obvious solutions to these equations are lines and circles, but I am looking for a teardrop like shape satisfying $x(0)=x(1)$, $x'(0)=1$, $x'(1)=-1$, $y(0)=y(1)$, $y'(0)=0$, $y'(1)=0$.

I would love analytic solutions, but I would even appreciate numerical methods for solving this strange boundary-value problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, lines and circles is all you get.

If $x' = u$ and $y' = v$, you have $u^2 + v^2 = 1$ so let $u = \cos(\theta)$ and $v = \sin(\theta)$.  Then the differential equation $x'''/x' = y'''/y'$ simplifies to $\theta''= 0$.  Thus the general solution has $\theta = A t + B$,
$u = \cos(At+B)$, $v = \sin(At+B)$, where $A$ and $B$ are constants.  If $A \ne 0$ you get $x = x_0 + \sin(At+B)/A$, $y = y_0 - \cos(At+B)/A$, thus a circle.  If $A = 0$, you get a straight line.